# Allow selection of text in read-only cells

Tags: handsontable

When making a cell `readOnly` in Handsontable (0.16), it no longer brings up the editor. Because of this, selecting the text on that cell becomes disabled as well.

Is there a way to re-enable user-select so that a user could highlight and copy text from these cells? Or any cells, even non-read-only cells.

Comment: Just wanted to make sure you checked out SelectCell API: http://docs.handsontable.com/0.15.1/demo-highlighting-current.html

Comment: what do you mean? that doesn't seem to have an application here, I think. All it does is programmatically select a cell. What I'm saying is that the only way to select text right now is by opening the editor (double clicking, for example) and then it allows selecting. If you make a cell read-only, then you can never highlight text. Highlighting text means if you have a word, being able to highlight part of it and then copy/pasting it.

Comment: That's correct. Not sure how you can highlight a read only cell. Curious to know the solution.

Comment: This is probably the default behavior. HOT is catching the click-drag event and dismissing it so that it doesn't interfere with the editor. It should just be remove when a cell is read-only.